# Incremental Spatial Autocorrelation Tool in QGIS

Tags: qgis, autocorrelation

I would like to know if there is a QGIS alternative /tool or plugin/ to Arcmap tool "Incremental Spatial Autocorrelation". The tool is very handy for distance threshold definition by hot spot analysis.